# I'm new to flutter and I ran into an error while running my first app

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, android-emulator

Finished with error: ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Saheed\AndroidStudioProjects\testin_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip


Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org


at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)


at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)


at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)


at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)


at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)


at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)


at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)`
```

Comment: This happens every time? It looks like a temporal network error.

Comment: I recommend switching to VS Code, and create your project using command `flutter create project_name`.

Comment: What is the output of `flutter doctor` command ?

Answer (score 0):

You Simply Need to Install android 9 and 8 in SDK Section. After installation restarts your IDE.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJt6Z.png)
Click here for Image Guide